# Get the script name from game object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a gameobject two scripts are attached with it. I want to get the name of second script from first script. 
**Remember**:

1. I don't want direct assignment (i know it very well).
2. First Script name can not be hard coded causes it will change.

*Consequentl*y, I want to get the script name and set that script property ?

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure what do you mean by *"I want to get the name of second script from first script"*, but take a look at this:

[image]

I have to scripts attached to Main Camera gameObject.

Here is the code of Test.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour 
{

    void Start()
    {
        MonoBehaviour[] scripts = this.GetComponents<MonoBehaviour> ();

        foreach (MonoBehaviour mb in scripts)
        {
            Debug.Log (mb.GetType ().Name);
        }
    }
}
```

On start it prints the names of all `MonoBehaviour`s on it:

[image]

Comment: now I have got the name of script it is in string format. how do i use it in getComponenet?

Answer (score 1):

This, while not straight-forward is a fairly easy way to do what you need.

Since [AddComponent](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html) no longer accepts a string (the docs indicate otherwise, but I assume it's because Unity hasn't gotten around to update it), what you can do is

1. Get the [Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) using [Type.GetType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. Use AddComponent(System.Type)

Code below

```
var type = Type.GetType("SomeClassName");
gameObject.AddComponent(type);
```